# Excel formulae to pick corresponding matrix value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can you help with the formulae which can provide me the corrresponding row/column value at the intersection point

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
A               X       
B       X               
C       X               
D                       
E               X       
F
```

Formulae should provide values as
AD
BB
CB
FD

Comment: look for the formula `INDEX()`

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is a Q&A site to get help with what you have already attempted and have become stuck. Is it not a formula/script writing service. Please update your question to include what you have researched and attempted.

Answer (score 1):

In **H2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(A2 & INDEX($A$1:$G$1,MATCH("X",A2:G2,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]